# Best practice for session verification on consequent requests after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, redis

I'm working on a multi role Node Application which uses `express-session`, Redis and MongoDB. The application has a primary account under which there can be multiple users from different accounts with corresponding roles who can be logged in at one time.

The database has documents with many to many relations. When a user is logged in, then the session would exist for some definite time. I'm using middleware to verify the user for any subsequent requests to the API after they have successfully logged in.

Let's say two users are working with the documents under the same account and their sessions were already created some time before. What's the best practice to verify if the account still exists for other user if one user deletes the account.

I see two scenarios :-

1. Check if the account exists on every request in the middleware. I'm just worried about the load it would put on the database. As every request that comes in would first need the account to be verified if it exists or not.
2. Instead of verifying in the middleware. Checking if the account exists when updating the documents. In this scenario i would be putting repeatable logic to verify existence of account when ever someone tries to find/create/update/delete any document or subdocument that exists within the account.

What do you guys think is the efficient way to implementing account existence verifying after a session is created. My session collection exists in Redis and documents in MongoDb

Comment: How many do accounts you have? Are they deleted frequently? Otherwise, can't you store that in Redis?

Comment: The accounts would be in few thousands. Not deleted frequently. I'm only storing the session info in Redis at the moment

Comment: Instead of storing only sessions, can't you put in Redis also the existence of every single account? I am a newbie on Redis but considering that you have a few thousands of accounts, you could run `set some_account_id` for each account, and query if it exists with `exists some_account_id`. Obviously you keep them in a different keyspace than the one with sessions. You do not have many data, it should be very performant, since it is in memory.

Comment: re-reading this question, it sounds like the documents need to become read-only. if that's the case, after deleting the account it would make sense to mark all its documents as read-only or archived. Then you won't need to cross-reference any relationships.

Comment: also, whether you choose to check if the account exists or if the document is read-only, you'd only need to run the check on create, update and delete actions. otherwise, if you have to prevent users from viewing those documents completely, it'd make more sense to delete them too along with the account.